# Is there any way to create a Secondary axis in SSRS 2005

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I am working on a report in SSRS 2005 that needs a chart to have a secondary axis.

The suggestion of using a third party application is not allowed.

It's a strict requirement to get that secondary axis and its value in the chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Secondary axes were [added in SSRS 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281176.aspx), so you can't do it in your version.

If you can't upgrade then about the best you can do is scale one set of values. For example, divide Series A by 1,000 and put in the legend `Series A (000s)`.